# traverse pointer from last node to first

Tags: c

```
bn_ptr drive_temp(bn_ptr head,bn_ptr temp,bn_ptr current)
{

    while(temp->next!=current)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
        current=temp;
    }
    temp=head;

    return current; 
}
```

I have linked list and 'head' pointer hold  first node , 'current' pointer hold  last node,I want to bring 'current' to head one by one ,so I write this function but it gives segmentation fault when I debug the program

Comment: `while(temp->next!=current)` should be `while(temp && temp->next!=current)`, otherwise you would dereference a NULL pointer, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: There isn't a really convenient way to traverse a singly linked list backward... you can use a double linked list instead, or reverse the list first and traverse the reversed list forward.

Comment: mch I tried your answer but it is not solved ,I dont want to reverse list  thank you for answers

Comment: what is the point of having 'temp' as a parameter?

Comment: I learned it new ,temp was not necessarily , thank yo @SelçukCihan

Answer (score 0):

`temp->next!=current` will never be true unless `temp==temp->next`.

Try this:

```
bn_ptr drive_temp(bn_ptr head,bn_ptr temp,bn_ptr current)
{

    while(temp->next!=current)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    current=temp; /* get this out of the loop */
    temp=head;

    return current; 
}
```

or more simplified this:

```
bn_ptr drive_temp(bn_ptr head,bn_ptr temp,bn_ptr current)
{
    (void)head; /* head isn't used, so put this to avoid warning */
    while(temp->next!=current)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    /* current and temp will be lost, so assigning to them here is useless */

    return temp; 
}
```

To make it safer, make sure that `temp` isn't `NULL` to avoid runtime error in case of `current` is invalid.

```
bn_ptr drive_temp(bn_ptr head,bn_ptr temp,bn_ptr current)
{
    (void)head; /* head isn't used, so put this to avoid warning */
    while(temp != NULL && temp->next!=current)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }

    /* temp will be the previous node of current or NULL */
    return temp; 
}
```

Maybe you want this:

```
bn_ptr drive_temp(bn_ptr head,bn_ptr current) /* remove temp from the arguments */
{
    bn_ptr temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL && temp->next!=current)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }

    /* temp will be the previous node of current or NULL */
    return temp; 
}
```

Comment: @ameyCU It shouldn't be. Casting to `void` game me [no errors nor warnings](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sh88B0VLjn5jwXbV), and casting to `void*` gave me [a warning](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nBrMF9ayGbUDCjae).

Comment: That is just a warning of unused variable. But I am surprised it didn't gave anything with `void` .

Comment: @ameyCU Why the cast **should be** `void *` despite of the warning? Why do you **want** the warning?

Comment: @MikeCAT i am grateful to you ,your codes worked a lot ,and thank you ameyCU