# Casting pointer to void

Tags: c, pointers, void

Is there any difference in below two castings ?

```
int a=10;
int *p=&a;

(void)p;          //does not give any warning or error
```

or

```
(void *)p;        //error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
```

when complied with `gcc -Wall -Werror --std=c99 -pedantic`

[Just saw that in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127075/traverse-pointer-from-last-node-to-first/33127236?noredirect=1#comment54067159_33127236)  (clearly I misunderstood something )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, obviously.

```
 (void)p;
```

means the object is getting casted to `void` type, (which is not a complete type) and that being the complete expression, the result of the expression should not be used, hence compiler does not check for it's usage.

Quoting `C11` standard, chapter 6.3.2.2, `void`

> The (nonexistent) value of a `void` expression (an expression that has type void) shall not
>   be used in any way,[......] If an expression of any other type is evaluated as a `void`
>   expression, its value or designator is discarded.

So, no warning or error is generated.

OTOH,

```
(void *)p;
```

means the object is a pointer to `void` type, which is a complete type and should be used in your program. In that case, the non-usage of the object out of the expression is rightly reported by the compiler.

Comment: With the former casting value at address pointed by `p`, does that  have any change ?

Comment: @ameyCU nopes. Only if there is s side effect, that will make effect, which is not the case here.

Comment: And casting `p` again to `int *` will be safe ?

Comment: @ameyCU yes, it will, but you won't be needing that.

Comment: Why would I not need that  ? Because I am casting to `void` in first place ?

Comment: @ameyCU but did you store it anywhere? :)

Comment: then why should have it any effect on `p` itself? :)

Comment: To elaborate, the supression of that sort of warning is largely what casts to void are for.  In this specific example, the statement is indistinguishable from the empty expression, but in other cases there may be side-effects.  Casting to void is a way to inform the compiler that while you may care about the side-effects, you don't care about the expession's value.  e.g. printf("Foo\n") evaluates to 4 (the number of characters printed) if it is successful, or a negative value otherwise. (void)printf("Foo\n") just prints Foo\n as best it can and doesn't evaluate to anything.

Answer (score 15):

When you do

```
(void) p;
```

You tell the compiler to simply disregard the result of the expression `p`. It's effectively the same as an empty statement:

```
;
```

---

When you do

```
(void *) p;
```

You tell the compiler to treat the variable `p` as a generic pointer, and that's the full expression for the statement, an expression which doesn't really do anything and you get the error message.

Comment: can you give some real-world-use of this feature?

Comment: @DavidHaim: I've seen it in cases where certain local variables are only used inside an `IFDEF`, to make it so that it doesn't raise warnings when compiled with settings that take the `ELSE` branch.

Comment: lol, so declare the local variable inside the ELSE branch if it's the only place that touches it. or I guess it's commping from a period where you ahd to declare all the variables together at the start of the scope..

Comment: "It's effectively the same as an empty statement" -> pretty much any expression in C can have side effects. This answer currently implies that a compiler might reduce `(void)sideEffectingFunction(a = b, c++);` down to `;`, which is obviously not the case.

Comment: @Leushenko Of course it's not the *general* case, but for *this* case it's basically equivalent.

Comment: @DavidHaim Casting a variable to `void` is a way to silence potential compiler warnings about unused function arguments.

Comment: @DavidHaim ↑ That can be seen as an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28382691/3049655)